# how to determine dependencies

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I'm currently learning java and want to create a project, using maven, hibernate and MySQL. I know that in order to use any of the artifacts with maven, I should find it on mvnrepository and add it to pom.xml. The question is where can I get the list of mandatory dependencies for each artifact I use, f.ex if I need hibernate, I found hibernate-core 4.3.8.Final, proceed to this link and can see it's dependencies in section "depends on". Should I add all of them into pom.xml also?

Comment: No. The _whole point_ of Maven is that you say you depend on `hibernate-core`, then `hibernate-core` tells Maven what it depends on. In this way Maven resolves a **dependency tree**.  So all you have to do is depend on Hibernate. You will also need a connection pool, and the MySQL connector to provide a `DataSource` to Hibernate, but that's really a configuration issue.

Comment: I've found an example on http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/quick-start-maven-hibernate-mysql-example/ and there is a section 7 about pom file config. Please look, the author says:"Modify the Maven’s pom.xml file, add support for Hibernate and MySQL. Hibernate is required dom4j, commons-logging, commons-collections and cglib as dependency library, add it." Where did he get this info? I mean, f.ex if I look to mvnrepository and search his version of hibernate I see a lot of more artifacts hibernate is dependent on, than those, that this autor has stated

Comment: See [Optional Dependencies](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-project-dependencies.html#pom-relationships-sect-optional) for situations where you have to define transitive dependencies explicitly. But, none of the 4 which mykong mentions is declared as `optional` in [org.hibernate:hibernate:3.2.3.ga:pom](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate/3.2.3.ga/hibernate-3.2.3.ga.pom). So, it's not clear to me why they are mentioned to be declared due to being required by Hibernate at mykong. According to the dependency mechanism this isn't necessary.

Comment: thank you, Gerold, for your answers

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think you know about **maven**.

And yes, You should include all the **dependencies** with version on your **pom.xml** files (Which is the main file for all your dependencies ).

First, you need to identify all required dependencies and add on pom file.

While executing code, It primarily tries to get that dependency from **local repository (.m2)** And if it doesn't exists then it downloads from it's **web repository**.

Link: [maven setup](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_quick_guide.htm)

### How it works??

Suppose, You are using **log4j** for loggin. 
You need to know the log4j Maven coordinates,

**for example**

```
<groupId>log4j</groupId>
<artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
<version>1.2.14</version>
```

**It will download the log4j version 1.2.14 library automatically**. If the “version” tag is ignored, it will upgrade the library automatically when there is a newer version.

**Declares Maven coordinates into pom.xml file.**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.14</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

When Maven is compiling or building, the log4j jar will be downloaded automatically and put it into your Maven local repository.
All manages by Maven.

**How to find the Maven coordinates?**

Visit this [Maven center repository](http://search.maven.org/), search the jar you want to download.

Hope, It will help.

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't _"You should include all the **dependencies**"_ a bit confusing comparing it with @Boristhespider's correct comment to the question? I'd rather say "include all _direct_ dependencies [only]" Also, _"from its **web repository**"_ isn't always true. In case an organization runs a repository manager (like Artifatory, Nexus, ...) in its intranet.

Comment: Gerold Broser, so where can I get the list of **direct** dependencies? Please look through my previous comment

Comment: Sanjaya Pandey, the problem is that log4j doesn't have direct dependencies, at least I don't see them on: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j/1.2.14. However, as I have already mentioned the guy on the site: http://mkyong.com/hibernate/quick-start-maven-hibernate-mysql-example uses Hibernate and says that Hibernate depends on: dom4j, commons-logging, commons-collections and cglib, however I found more excessive list here:http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate/3.2.3.ga So who is right, he? or website?

Comment: @Sabine See [Maven, Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism, Transitive Dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies): _"This allows you to avoid needing to discover and specify the libraries that your own dependencies require, and including them automatically."._ With _"direct dependencies"_ I meant what is called _"your own dependencies"_ there. Which are the dependencies your application requires depending on the libraries/artifacts/functionality you'd like to use in it.